# Disable auto-close on modal forms

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on an ASP.Net project using bootstrap and I'm using a modal form for my register system. The problem is that the form close automatically when I click on register. I would like it to stay open so I can take care of the registration server-side.

Here's the code of my register box...

```
<!-- Register Box -->
        <div class="modal" id="register" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Register</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div runat="server" class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger" id="RegisterAlert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                            <asp:Label Text="" id="AlertLabel" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="inputDefault">Nom d'utilisateur</label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-control" ID="RegisterUserTextBox" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="inputDefault">Mot de passe</label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="password" class="form-control" ID="RegisterPasswordTextBox" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="inputDefault">Confirmez votre mot de passe</label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="password" class="form-control" ID="RegisterConfirmPasswordTextBox" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="inputDefault">Email</label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-control" ID="RegisterEmailTextBox" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Register" class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="Register_Click" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Whats inside Register_Click?

Comment: It's not coded yet, I still have to do the membership part, i'm pretty much checking if all the informations are correct
http://pastebin.com/4EuhFWz0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are posting back data using the asp:Button.  That will cause a post back and refresh the page, as the Onclick is calling server side code.  if you want to keep the modal up, try posting the data from client side, using Ajax.

Comment: As much as I would like to use Ajax, i'm a student and I don't know how to use it yet, is there anything else I can use instead of Ajax? Else, I will just find a workaround and make the register form on a different page.

Comment: Without ajax would be tricky.  You could do the post back, update a session value or pass a parameter in the url to signify that it was done.  when the page load if that value is there it could trigger the popup via javascript.  try this: https://sandywebdesigner.wordpress.com/2014/08/18/using-c-code-to-force-bootstrap-modal-stay-open-after-page-postback/  otherwise just break it to another page like you said.

Comment: @Paritosh is correct, without AJAX this will probably need some dirty workaround. 

One that comes to my mind is to reopen a model window on submit.